# Excel Sumif formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to create a SumIf formula that adds multiple columns together based on one criteria.

=sumif(F$8:F$58,F73,L$8:L$58+I$8:I$58)

This is giving me an error and will not add the two columns together.

Comment: You'll want two Sumif formulas. One for both L and I columns. Add these together. Or use Sumproduct (slower)

Comment: next time when asking a question like this it is a good practice to include some sample data with expected result :]

Answer (score 2):

You'd need

```
=sumif(F$8:F$58,F73,L$8:L$58) + sumif(F$8:F$58,F73,I$8:I$58)
```

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend you make it a practice to use `SUMIFS` instead of `SUMIF` even if you only have one criteria. The order makes more sense (what you're summing first), and it scales easier. Say you want to start adding more criteria, now you'll have to readjust the order of the inputs, whereas with `Sumifs` you simply just add to the criteria.

```
=sumifs(L$8:L$58,F$8:F$58,F73) + sumifs(I$8:I$58,F$8:F$58,F73)
```

Answer (score 1):

In case of summing multiple ranges, you can also try [SUMPRODUCT](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-sumproduct-function)

```
=SUMPRODUCT((F$8:F$58=F73)*((L$8:L$58)+(I$8:I$58)))
```

> The logic is similar to **SUMIFS**, `(F$8:F$58=F73)` sets the criteria while `((L$8:L$58)+(I$8:I$58))` defines the range to be summed.

Let me know if you have any questions. Cheers :)